# how to fetch anchor href attribute for <div class="_6ks"> shown in below screen shot using selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

how to fetch anchor href attribute for  shown in below screen shot using selenium in Java

[image]

Comment: It doesn't have `href` attribute, the child `<a>` has. What did you try and what was the problem with it?

Comment: yes i wanted to fetch from child element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fetch the anchor node href value and the class name is not dynamic and it is unique, then you can do like below :

```
WebElement elemnent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='_6ks']/a"));
String url = elemnent.getAttribute("href");
System.out.println("=> The URL is : "+url);
```

If the above one doesn't work then share the full html code in the text format so that it will be easy for us to track down that element.

Comment: `_6ks` looks to be a dynamic class. Better to look for static attributes.

Comment: @DebanjanB, thank you. I have mentioned(`the class name is not dynamic and it is unique`) it in the problem description.

Comment: Ok @DebanjanB, Thank you, I will try to use the static attribute from now on wards.

Comment: Ahhh, putting it straight, at times you do have to take into account the _dynamic_ attributes but only the _static part_

Comment: @user2940827 since you said this answer worked for you, please mark it as the accepted answer.